# Lubuntu 16.04,: Why can't I open hotmail without adding additional DNS server?

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, dns

After I upgraded from Lubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 I have had problems using my hotmail account.  It has worked sometimes, but now it is almost impossible to connect.  The browser reports 'server not found'.

I googled extensively and found a whole load of issues relating to Firefox - resolved by clearing cookies, changing dns and ipv6 config etc, etc...

After diabling DNS prefetch and ipv6 in Firefox configuration, hotmail started working immediately.  Hooray !  Only to pack in again after a few days.

I gave up on Firefox and installed Chrome.  No change !  I tried another machine with Lubuntu 16.04 - exactly the same, I cannot open hotmail.

Conclusion:  This is nothing to do with the browser.  It is Lubuntu 16.04 that is giving the problem.

Finally I found an article that suggested adding 8.8.8.8 as an additional DNS server in preferences | network connections | wifi | ipv4 Settings.  That fixed the problem !

**What did I do and why did I need to do it ?**

**Why did hotmail work sporadically at the beginning, and again after the change in Firefox settings ?**